# Problem with Principal Component Analysis in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, weighted-overlay

I am doing research using ArcGIS for selection of potential sites for small-scale irrigation in Burkina Faso. I have the following layers: aquifer types, LULC, precipitation, slope, soil type, distance to streams. I already used AHP, and I want to compare it with more machine-based tool, such as PCA, and eventually compare the two results between each other.
I know how to create PCA analysis for continuous float values, but there is a problem with Soil types, Aquifer types and Soil types maps (which are discrete). The result of the Eigen values is bizarre.
How can I solve the problem?